# Showing only email apps in chooser when starting an activity with ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, email

when starting an activity with ACTION_SEND intent I get a menu with gmail, facebook, bluetooth... How can I get only email apps in this menu?

Thanks

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{email});
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I gave the same answer earlier and you accept another one. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I accepted the first one in the list. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried action ACTION_SENDTO and setting your email as a data? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO
You always also can use explicit call of needed activity.

Comment: Hi, I need to start skype from my application. can you please indicate what activity I need to specify in the intent()? thanks

Comment: I have no idea. P.S. Don't ask questions in comments, add new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`ACTION_SENDTO` instead of `ACTION_SEND`